# Identity system User is always null in the action method of custom remote validation attribute in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, remote-validation, validationattribute

I am developing an Asp.net mvc web application. In my application, I need to implement, custom remote validation attribute. I can implement it successfully. But it is having problem with User of identity system in controller action method that is remote validation method.

This is my full remote validation attribute class

```
public class RemoteClientServerAttribute : RemoteAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Get the controller using reflection
        Type controller = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name.ToLower() == string.Format("{0}Controller",
                this.RouteData["controller"].ToString()).ToLower());
        if (controller != null)
        {
            // Get the action method that has validation logic
            MethodInfo action = controller.GetMethods()
                .FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name.ToLower() ==
                    this.RouteData["action"].ToString().ToLower());
            if (action != null)
            {
                // Create an instance of the controller class
                //object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(controller);
                object instance = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(controller);
                // Invoke the action method that has validation logic
                object response = action.Invoke(instance, new object[] { value });
                if (response is JsonResult)
                {
                    object jsonData = ((JsonResult)response).Data;
                    if (jsonData is bool)
                    {
                        return (bool)jsonData ? ValidationResult.Success :
                            new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
        // If you want the validation to fail, create an instance of ValidationResult
        // return new ValidationResult(base.ErrorMessageString);
    }

    public RemoteClientServerAttribute(string routeName)
        : base(routeName)
    {
    }

    public RemoteClientServerAttribute(string action, string controller)
        : base(action, controller)
    {
    }

    public RemoteClientServerAttribute(string action, string controller,
        string areaName)
        : base(action, controller, areaName)
    {
    }
}
```

Let's imagine I have view model class like this

```
public class UpdateAccountModel
{
    [Required]
    [RemoteClientServer("IsNameUnique", "Account" , ErrorMessage = "Username is already taken")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [RemoteClientServer("IsEmailUnique", "Account" , ErrorMessage = "Email is already taken")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see above, I am checking name is unique or not. For email address as well. Consider it as a view model for updating user profile. So user is currently logged in. So to check name is unique, I will check removing the current logged user value. For example, currently logged email is "example@gmail.com". If the user enter same email for email, validation will pass. But if the email exist with different account, validation will fail.

This is the remove validation action method for checking unique email

```
public JsonResult IsEmailUnique(string Email)
{
    bool isUnique = false;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email))
    {
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();//Error throws here because User is null
        isUnique = _userRepo.Users.Any(x => x.Email.Trim() == Email.Trim() && x.Id != userId) == false;
    }
    return Json(isUnique, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As you can see in the remove validation action method, I am retrieving current Logged in user. But it returns null. I have no idea why. But I can retrieve in the other action method. For example, in the edit profile action. I can retrieve like this.

```
public ActionResult EditAccount()
{
    var name = User.Identity.GetUserName();// This is working fine when I directly access from url.
    //do other stuffs
}
```

Why User of Asp.net Identity System is always null in the action method of remove validation attribute please? I do not want to pass the UserId as the parameter. Because user can change it very easily. I just want to retrieve it internally.

Answer (score 0):

Try `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();` instead of `User.Identity.GetUserId();`

Comment: Cannot call HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId in controller action method. I called ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId(); instead. I called HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();  as well. What I found out is controller context also null. Both throws null exception.